# Error in excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();" when hosted in server machine..[dcomcnfg]

Tags: configuration, dcom

The following is the code which thows error when hosted in Server PC.

```
try
{
    //Variable Declarations
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = null;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet NwSheet = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet NwSheetSummary;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet NwSheetIndividualTotal;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range ShtRange;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheets;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

    excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

    excel.Quit();
    excel = null;

    //Opening Excel file(myData.xlsx)
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Template/Template.xlsx"), Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    sheets = workbook.Worksheets;
    foreach (Worksheet ws in sheets)
    {
        if (ws.Index == 5)
            NwSheet = ws;
        if (ws.Index == 1)
            NwSheetSummary = ws;
        if (ws.Index == 4)
            NwSheetIndividualTotal = ws;
    }

    //Reading Excel file.
    //Creating datatable to read the containt of the Sheet in File.
    System.Data.DataTable dt = export.Tables[0];

    int rowCount = 8;

    if (dt.Columns.Contains("RowID"))
        dt.Columns.Remove("RowID");
    if (dt.Columns.Contains("Week"))
        dt.Columns.Remove("Week");
    if (dt.Columns.Contains("Year"))
        dt.Columns.Remove("Year");
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {

        rowCount += 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            // Add the header the first time through 
            if (rowCount == 8)
            {
                //NwSheet.Cells[1, i] = dt.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
            }
            NwSheet.Cells[rowCount, i] = dr[i - 1].ToString();
        }
    }

    for (int count = 0; count <= dt.Rows.Count; count++)
    {
        // NwSheet.get_Range("A9", Missing.Value).Value2 = dt.Rows[count]["SlNo"].ToString();


    }
    workbook.RefreshAll();
    String path = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultPath"]);

    CreateFileOrFolder(workbook, week);
    NwSheet = null;
    ShtRange = null;
    workbook.Close(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    workbook = null;
    oXL.Quit();
    excel.Quit();
    //appExl.Quit();
    status = true;
}
```

Now it run's fine in my local PC which has `Interop Excel 12.0` but not when hosted in server machine which has same `12.0`.

the error received is

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005.

After googling out for the error I had gone through other forums and they had mentioned to `give rights to Network Services to Microsoft Excel Application in dcomcnfg`. I did the same thing but its of no use.

It didnt worked out and I got the same error.
Like :- 
[Configuration of dcomcnfge](http://blog.crowe.co.nz/archive/2006/03/02/589.aspx)

Which Say's:-

> Goto Control-Panel --> Administrative tools-->Component Services -->computers --> myComputer -->DCOM Config --> Microsoft Excel Application. --> Right click to get properties dialog. Goto Security tab and customize permissions accordingly.

I have tried giving all possible right's but still the error persist's.!!

Please help..

Comment: [Excel is not designed to be run on servers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757). If you're trying to automate it from a service, you might be heading towards a brick wall... It's not only a matter of permissions, when running as a service you don't have an interactive desktop, and Excel doesn't like that. There are similar questions here about this topic, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234615/excel-com-automation-stops-working-when-user-logs-off) for instance.